# Creating a nested class in django and running a helper method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've the following User model,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And this is my Meeting model

```
class Meeting(Base):
    meeting_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='meetings', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='meeting_set', null=True, blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

When a meeting is created, I want to run this helper function to generate a meeting code

```
def generate_meetingid():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=16))
```

This is my meeting serializer,

```
class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = ['id', 'meeting_code', 'owner', 'members', 'start_time', 'end_time', ]
```

My questions is how do I write the Meeting View set that adds the creating user as the owner and  also runs the helper method to create the meeting code.
In essence, I'm trying to complete this view,

```
class MeetingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the `save` method, while I usually prefer using `pre_save` signal. The logic is similar to generating a unique `slug` for model instance, the helper function is automatically invoked before you save the object. In your serializer you can simply mark `meeting_code` as `read_only` so the `meeting_code` is not used when creating or updating the instance during deserialization

```
# override save method
class Meeting(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # avoid meeting_code IntegrityError
        # self._state.adding == True means item was not added in the database yet
        if self._state.adding and not self.meeting_code:
            self.meeting_code = generate_meetingid()
            while Meeting.objects.filter(meeting_code=self.meeting_code).exists():
                self.meeting_code = generate_meetingid()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


# pre_save signal
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Meeting)
def generate_meeting_code(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        # on meeting create
        meeting=kwargs.get('instance')
        meeting.meeting_code = generate_meetingid()
        while Meeting.objects.filter(meeting_code=self.meeting_code).exists():
            meeting.meeting_code = generate_meetingid()
```

#### Serializer

```
class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = ['id', 'meeting_code', 'owner', 'members', 'start_time', 'end_time', ]
        read_only_fields = ['meeting_code']
```

#### Views

```
class MeetingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # pass owner to the serializer
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: thanks while this works fine, I was wondering what does the call inside the while loop do?

Comment: @root it ensures meeting_code to be unique and does not conflict with the ones saved before.